# Finite generation is hereditary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $U \subseteq V \subseteq W$ be three rings. If we assume that $M$ is a finitely generated $U$-submodule of $W$, when $M$ is also a $V$-submodule, then it can be shown that $M$ is also finitely generated.

Is it true that if $M$ is a finitely generated $V$-submodule of $W$, then it is also a finitely generated $U$-submodule of $W$?

Comment: No. Try to make $V$ much larger than $U$. (Btw, it would probably be better not to use the word "hereditary", as this word has a meaning in algebra.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Qi Zhu says, this is not true in general. For example, let $U=k$ be your favorite field, and take $M=V=W=k[x]$ to be the polynomial ring in one variable over $k$. Then $M$ is trivially finitely generated as a $V$-module, but it has infinite $k$-dimension and is hence not finitely generated as a $U$ module.

Comment: More simply, If I take a ring $R$ containing a non-finitely generated ideal $I$ and consider the ring itself first as a module over $R$ and next over $I$?

Comment: dear @TheWanderer, unfortunately that example does not quite work, unless you are considering non-unital rings! in general, an ideal of a ring $R$ will be a subring of $R$ if and only if it is equal to $R$. so, if you do assume that your rings are unital, then it doesn't quite make sense in general to ask about $R$ as a module over $I$ :)